# node-request ip addres different from remote ip address

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, node-request

I have a app that uses node and request. It was working well until today, I dont know why but it stoped to work. I'm trying to do a simple request.get() to a specific page and it is sending me a timed out error, but the address the lib tried to access is different from remote adddress. It seems that node-request is not converting the url to proper ip for some reason.

request call:

```
request.get({
    url: 'http://www.website.to.request.com:8000/login.aspx',
    headers: headers,
}
```

Node error message:

```
address:"200.200.00.00"
code:"ETIMEDOUT"
 errno:"ETIMEDOUT"
message:"connect ETIMEDOUT 200.200.00.00:8000"
port:8000
stack:"Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 200.200.00.00:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)" syscall:"connect"
```

request in chrome debug:

```
Request URL:http://www.website.to.request.com:8000/login.aspx
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:201.11.11.111:8000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Note: If I try to access: `201.11.11.111:8000/login.aspx` it works, but with `200.200.00.00:8000` not works.

if i try to get the page content using https://www.hurl.it/ and passing the url and content-type works too;

Someone has any idea what this request is wrong??

Comment: Does the hostname resolve to multiple IP-numbers, of which one isn't reachable?

Comment: Host name should resolve to 201.11.11.111:8000 as chromes debug shows. But node-request is resolving to  200.200.00.00:8000. Seems like cache from somewhere. if I change `request.get({
    url: 'http://www.website.to.request.com:8000/login.aspx'` to `request.get({
    url: 'http://201.11.11.111:8000/login.aspx'` it works. But I dont want the ip hard coded.

Comment: What is that port 8072 that's being mentioned in the error message? Do you have a proxy configured? If you're on Linux or macOS, what does `host www.website.to.request.com` return?

Comment: Sorry 8072 was the original port I changed it to 8000 in my question. When I try to acces on browser the url `www.website.to.request.com` whitout port, it shows 403 -
 Forbidden `Directory Listing Denied`. If I access `www.website.to.request.com:8000` with the correct port it shows the correct webpage.

Comment: Try setting the `followRedirect` and `followAllRedirects` options to `false`. Perhaps it connects to the correct server at first, but it gets redirected to the 200.200.00.00 address.

Comment: Good guess, but unfortunately not worked.

Comment: I did nothing and it's working now. Maybe the client has changed the IP and for some reason the request was trying on the old one. After some time the DNS that 'request' uses may have been updated.

Comment: That would explain it, although it doesn't really make sense if you were running both the client and the browser from the same machine. You would expect both to be using the same DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hardcode a DNS request, before the requestjs call, and then you can set the request url with the ip you got back.

This is the api you can use to execute the DNS lookup:
https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html

Remember that you can use dns.setServers to hardcode some dns servers (['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4'] for google DNS)